# PHPMailer stuck on "Connection: opened"

Tags: php, phpmailer

Bellow is my code used to send an email. PHPMailer output messages are:

```
2019-01-19 13:47:42        Connection: opening to xxxxxx:465, timeout=5, options=array()  
2019-01-19 13:47:42     Connection: opened
```

I tried with a wrong password and nothing changes. Does anyone has an ideea what it may happen?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->Host = 'xxxxxxx';                      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication


$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx@xxx.xxx';            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                         // SMTP password



$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
$mail->addAddress('xxxxx', 'xxxxx');                            // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Timeout  =   5;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $text;

$mail->send();
```

Comment: $mail->send() ?

Comment: @Eric sorry. I forgot to add it in question, but not in script. I edited the question. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: This isn't reproducible to anyone. Code excerpt irrelevant. Investigate network issues.

Comment: Use $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; for SERVER debug

Comment: @Martin I wrote timeout 5 just for testing purposes. Even this does not trigger an error.

Comment: @mario Got any tips for that?

Comment: Look through all the similar questions on such issues; lots of tips already there.

Comment: @mario I spent more than one hour looking for something similar and I haven't found anything (not even in the official troubleshooting guide). That's the reason I asked here.

Comment: BTW, SMTPDebug = 3 is appropriate for debugging connection problems. 2 does not show low-level connection issues, only client and server SMTP traffic, but in this case it’s not getting as far as talking SMTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **is** a code problem, not a network issue.

You’re connecting to port 465, which is typically used for implicit TLS (i.e. it expects you to talk TLS immediately), known as SMTPS, but you have not told PHPMailer to do that, so it will just hang, as you’re seeing. Fix it by setting that TLS mode:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'll test it in a few hours and come back with an reply.

Comment: It was a SSL issue, but because of certificate used in the process. I've seen that this answer was not closed and that's why I came back at it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer saved me from being stuck at exactly the same point.
All of the examples I was looking at had:

`$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Changed that one line to:

`$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

And the message went out no problem.